# How can I create two admin users for my website?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, web-applications

I currently have an admin user for my website called "SYSTEM", this user has full access rights to the website and is able to add/delete user credentials. I have created another user called "trainer" which has the same permission level. However when I test my webapp the "trainer" user is restricted and is unable to add/delete users. My code is below, can anyone help?

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        StringBuilder SB = new StringBuilder();
        UserModel a = (UserModel)ViewData["UserMaint"];
        List<String> UserList = a.getUserList();
        List<String> CountryList = a.getCountryList();
        SB.Append("<input type=\"hidden\" id=\"UserMaintActionURL\" value=\"");
      //  SB.Append("<input type=\"hidden\" id=\"User\" value=\"");
      //  SB.Append(ApplicationUtility.FormatURL("/Stock/Login"));
        SB.Append("\" />");

        litLoginActionHidden.Text = SB.ToString();

        if (ViewData["ERROR"] != null)
        {
            errormsg.Text = ViewData["ERROR"].ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            errormsg.Text = " ";
        }
        SB = new StringBuilder();
        SB.Append("<input type=\"hidden\" id=\"User\" name=\"User\" value=\"" + a.GetCurrentUser().ToUpper() + "\" />");
        SB.Append("<select name=\"textUser\" id name=\"textUser\" onchange=\"onChangeUser()\">");

        foreach (String element in UserList)
        {
            if (a.GetCurrentUser().ToUpper()==element.ToUpper()||a.GetCurrentUser().ToUpper() == "SYSTEM" || a.GetCurrentUser().ToUpper() == "trainer")
            {
                if (a.GetUser().ToUpper() == element.ToUpper())
                {
                    SB.Append("<option value=\"" + element + "\" selected >" + element + "</option>");
                }
                else
                {
                    SB.Append("<option value=\"" + element + "\">" + element + "</option>");
                }
            }
                    }
        SB.Append("</select>");
        litUserMaint.Text = SB.ToString();
        SB = new StringBuilder();
        SB.Append("<select name=\"textCntry\" id name=\"textCntry\" >");
        if (a.GetCurrentCntry().ToUpper() == "ALL"||a.GetCurrentUser().ToUpper() == "SYSTEM" || a.GetCurrentUser().ToUpper() == "trainer")
        {
            SB.Append("<option value=\"ALL\">ALL</option>");
        }
                    foreach (String element in CountryList)
        {
            if (a.GetCurrentCntry().ToUpper() == element.ToUpper() || a.GetCurrentUser().ToUpper() == "SYSTEM" || a.GetCurrentUser().ToUpper() == "trainer") 
            {
                if (a.GetCountry().ToUpper() == element.ToUpper())
                {
                    SB.Append("<option value=\"" + element + "\" selected >" + element + "</option>");
                }

                else
                {
                    SB.Append("<option value=\"" + element + "\">" + element + "</option>");
                }

            }
        }

        SB.Append("</select>");             
        litCountryList.Text = SB.ToString();
        if (a.GetErrorMessage().Trim() != "")
        {
            StringBuilder ES = new StringBuilder();
            ES.Append("<table border=1><tr><td  class=\"ErrorText\">");
            ES.Append(a.GetErrorMessage().ToString());
            ES.Append("</td></tr></table>");
            errormsg.Text = ES.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            errormsg.Text = " "; 
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a logical error in your code.

```
if (a.GetCurrentUser().ToUpper()==element.ToUpper()||a.GetCurrentUser().ToUpper() == "SYSTEM" || a.GetCurrentUser().ToUpper() == "trainer")
```

string `a.GetCurrentUser().ToUpper() == "trainer"` will never be true.  You're evaluating an upper case string on the left to a lowercase string.

To fix it, you can either write:

```
a.GetCurrentUser().ToUpper() == "TRAINER"
```

Or:

```
a.GetCurrentUser().Equals("trainer", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
```

I'd also recommend only running `GetCurrentUser` at the beginning of the loop and then use the result if it's an expensive evaluation (even if it isn't), since you don't need to get it multiple times in the same method.

On the subject of your code; there are a few other issues with it:

- You're allowing the username to be displayed on the site with no HTML encoding in it.  If that username is ever shown to other users, someone could craft a malicious username that allows them to execute a XSS or SQL Injection attack (XSS for certain, SQL Injection in the case if you're also mistakenly not parameterizing your SQL inputs).\
- You've got a lot going on in your code, and trying to build HTML manually is neither fun. There are other ways; specifically using a view. Without knowing more about your set up, there's not much more I can say except "Don't do what you're doing" if you're ever in a work environment.